# Shopify Liquid: output variable to a .js file

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I have a `custom.js.liquid` file under my assets folder, and I have added this line to `theme.liquid`.

```
<script src="{{ 'custom.js' | asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>
```

I am trying to output a product's title to javascript, in `custom.js.liquid`, I put

```
console.log({{ all_products['absolut-vodka'] | json }});
```

This line can't be recognized by the .js.liquid file. In frontend, in the `custom.js` file it becomes

```
console.log(null);
```

On the other hand, if I put

```
<script>console.log({{ all_products['absolut-vodka'] | json}});</script>
```

in the `theme.liquid` file, it can output the correct object.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Not sure this is possible https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Using-liquid-in-javascript-trying-to-get-collection-title-in/td-p/89883 look at answer from Caroline_Schnap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asset files are resources that Shopify strongly caches. This means that you cannot access any Liquid variables that might be change from page to page, customer to customer, etc.  Product details can be updated at any arbitrary time by yourself or an app, so this also falls under the category of things that are not available in your asset files.

Inside your `.js.liquid` file, the main things you have access to are:

- Translation settings
- Theme settings

... and that's about it. It may be worth noting that theme and language settings are both located with your theme files, and this may have something to do with Shopify's decisions around these Liquid restrictions

If you want to get the product details for your `absolut-vodka` product, you can use Shopify's storefront API to get the details you need. (eg: by fetching `/products/some-product-handle.js`). For example:

```
function getProductThenDoStuff(productHandle, callbackFunction){
  fetch('/products/' + productHandle + '.js')
    .then(function(response){ return response.json() })
    .then(callbackFunction)
}
```