# show a varable in js.liquid that was set in liquid html

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

looking for something really basic there that does not see m to work. Not sure if I'm doing this wrong or if my files are set up wrong.

I can do this

liquid html

```
<span id="forATest_id">
  {{ product.title }} 
</span>
```

js.liquid

```
document.getElementById("forATest_id").innerHTML = "Put in from Js ";
```

that works but if I want to going the other way

HTML

```
{% assign test t= 42 %}
```

js.liquid

```
alert("{{ test }}");
```

I can not. I tried many examples and everything I try is blank or null.

I have also read the js.liquid can use liquid directly but this also does not seem to work. alert (  {{ user.ID}}  )  should have but is blank.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61778168/shopify-liquid-output-variable-to-a-js-file? The important thing to remember is that Liquid is compiled server-side to create a document that is sent to the browser, and assets like .js and .css files are separate from the HTML pages, so neither will be influenced by liquid variables in the other.

Comment: That does make sense yes, and I tried this  API fetch but although it didn't work I'm still thinking my question is a bit more basic. Can the js.liquid page not simply get a variable from the html liquid page? And if that is not possible why are there 100s of examples showing it possible.  I must be missing something very basic.

is this not what i'm doing? https://brentryanjohnson.com/jekyll-leaflet-variables/

Comment: this works

   {% assign test = 42 %}
   <script>console.log({{ test}});</script>

but I want to do that in js.liquid.

Comment: No, the js.liquid cannot read a Liquid variable from the HTML liquid page - the two are completely different documents being generated server-side and being sent to the user's browser. The rendered HTML in your first document that gets sent to the browser is simply `<script>console.log(42)</script>`, and your .js page will be compiled separately and will only be able to evaluate the Liquid included in that specific file.

Comment: Note that the article that you linked to is tagged `Jekyll` - Jekyll's implementation of Liquid is slightly different from Shopify's, so that may be the difference?  But it also looks like that example is using an HTML template as a way to transfer the Liquid information to the Javascript part.

Comment: but the point of js.liquid is to access the liquid stuff. So how is this different from normal js.

Comment: The js.liquid has access to things that are generally static to your store/theme - stuff like translation variables, theme settings, and high-level things like that.  You can read those setting variables to, for example, allow the store owner to toggle various settings through the theme settings page, or to dynamically render elements with text that can be translated or customized for that store. However, the actual contents of the final `myScriptFile.js` will be the same for every page load, which allows the user's browser to cache the file and reuse it for every page.

Comment: Ok let me slightly rephrase my fusion then. If I want to make a page and get data from shoplift, to use in "code" to make calls to functions in that code, how would one do this? I'm not limited to js here, but surly there is a way to use data from the store in code to do other things?